# how to create a scrollable datepicker in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

how can I create a scrollable datepicker like the image below? also I want to create something exactly like thisfor a heigh,weight picker

[image: datepicker]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [official CupertinoDatePicker](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoDatePicker-class.html) form the flutter team

[image]